# Datepicker hiding on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I need to hide a datepicker when a user moves their mouse away from an input where the datepicker is active. While it works, it works a bit *too well*. It also hides the datepicker when I try to mouse over it. Resizing the div isn't the best idea either as this is a dynamically generated data entry form. And only date fields are being generated with the .herd-evt-date class.

I need to know what to do to have jquery check if I'm mousing away from the textbox but not the datepicker. How does one do this?

```
$('#herd-evt-entry-tbl').on('focus','.herd-evt-date',function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {this.focus();},
    onClose: function() {this.focus();},
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  });
});
$('#herd-evt-entry-tbl').on('mouseleave','.herd-evt-date',function() {
  $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='herd-evt-menu-div'></div>
<div id='herd-evt-detail-div'>
  <h2><div id='herd-evt-name-div'>Mating Event</div></h2>
  <button id='herd-evt-back-btn'><-Back</button>
  <button id='herd-evt-columns-btn'>Column Info</button>
  <button id='herd-evt-file-upload-btn'>Upload File</button>
  <button id='herd-evt-save-btn'>Save Valid</button>
  <input type='hidden' id='herd-load-id-hdn' value='0' />
  <input type='hidden' id='herd-evt-id-hdn' value='0' />
  <table id='herd-evt-entry-tbl' border=1></table>
</div>
<div class='herd-event-columninfo-display'>
 <div><button id='herd-event-columninfo-close-btn'>X</button></div>
 <table id='herd-evt-columninfo-tbl'></table>
 <button id='herd-evt-columninfo-upd-btn'>Update</button>
</div>
<div class='herd-evt-dup'>
  <button style='float: right; ' id='herd-evt-dup-close'>X</button>
  <table id='herd-evt-dup-tbl'>
    <thead><th></th><th>Stig</th><th>Tattoo</th><th>Ident</th><th>Herdstat</th><th>State Day</th><th>Sex</th><th>Gen Level</th><th>Transponder</th><th>French Ident</th></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div></td></tr></table>
<div style='clear: both'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where's your html? Hard to troubleshoot events when we can't see the DOM

Comment: Example markup showing the unintended behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/2sxw84u6/

Comment: I added an update with the html. It might not be useful though considering the dynamic nature of the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could approach it like this:

```
$("#herd-evt-entry-tbl").hover(function () {
     // Do something on Mouse Over.
}, function () {
    // Do something on Mouse Off.
});
```

So if the entire `div` is the element `herd-evt-entry-tbl` then when the `div` element is hovered on or off it will perform your task. It will also be able to rebind the `display` to your visible object.  Which your line `$(this).datepicker('hide');` is actually applying `display: none;`, which may need to be modified when you mouse over again.

Comment: Yeah, it's a step in the direction I needed to go for it. Works for me, and remind me to have jquery updated at some point.